# Writing a Macro regarding Expiration Date - How to trigger a pop-up Message

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying so hard to write a VBA code for date expiry date, wherein a message is supposed to pop out, a warning for a due date approaching.
This is the code so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Dim cl As Range
   Set cl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DEADLINE").Range("A1, A2")

  If IsDate(cl) Then

  End If

     If Now >= cl Then
        MsgBox "Due dates approaching"
     If Range("A1, A2").Value > 25 Then
        End If


End If
End Sub
```

The encountered issue is that I cant set the Macros to work for more than one cell. (e.g. A1 and A2)
Please help me out with this, I would be much obliged to those who can help me to sort this out.
My idea is to write this code and make it viable for any cell in a column. 
For instance: "If ANY cell part of the column is representing a date closer to TODAY, let a message pop out when opening the worksheet."

Thank you so much in advance.

I'll be waiting for the desired outcome and assistance!

Comment: How close to today? 25 days out - is that supposed to be the limit?

Comment: Exactly, Everything which is closer than 25 days before TODAY.

Comment: So something like `If value BETWEEN Today() And Today() + 25 Then` I expect VBA would have to loop through cells and test if value meets criteria. Or there may be some Excel functions that could be called by VBA. This would be so easy with an SQL query in Access. Edit question to provide sample data.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the current script and the only difference to be in the defined range?